# One third of the inapp purchases of my apps get an automatic refund for no clear reason

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, wear-os

I have around 25 watchface apps published on the Wear OS playstore. Most of them have a premium inapp purchase that unlocks all the features.

Around July 2021, users started complaining that the purchase didn't work properly. The features were still locked despite them paying for the premium unlock. I realized that all these users were receiving an automatic refund after three days. This follows the Google policy mentionned in their documentation:

> If you do not acknowledge a purchase within three days, the user
> automatically receives a refund, and Google Play revokes the purchase.
> [Android Developer documentation link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#acknowledge)

I started to investigate my code to find the source of the problem, and see why it wasn't acknowledging the purchase. I couln't find anything wrong. I couldn't even replicate the issue since all my purchase tests were successfull. However, I noticed that since July 2021, the purchase flow that Google uses on Wear OS changed. You used to be able to complete the entire purchase process from your watch. From July 2021 onwards, you initiate the process on your watch, but then you must finish the process either on your phone, or in a web browser at the address `g.co/playcontinue`. Then, once the purchase is complete, the watch is notified and it acknowledges the purchase.

This is where the problem seems to lie. From time to time, my purchase tests show that the watch is not notified back. The callback doesn't work and therefore the app can't acknowledge the purchase. My question is **why is the callback so frequently malfunctioning?**

I can't reliably reproduce the issue. The purchase process works most of the time for me, on the emulator, on a real watch, in debug mode, in release mode. It just *sometimes fails*. Randomly it seems. That's all.

Here are some statistics I've put together to show how bad the situation is:
[image: Automatic refunds]
You can see that it started misbehaving around July 2021, that 95% of refunds (gray) are actually automatic refunds (black), and that it represents about 30% of all purchases. You can also see some strange behaviours, like the fact that from Feb 2022 to July 2022, the problem happened a lot less, but rose again from July onwards. Another conlcusion I draw is that my code is at least partially working, it the sense that purchases are properly conducted most of the time. Something, somewhere, makes it fail somehow but I'm not able to find out what and why.

I have no clue how to troubleshoot this issue. I don't know how to reliably replicate the problem, I don't know if there's a way to access the logs of the apps that misbehave, I'm really lost. Any idea oh how to investigate this would be much appreciated.

Here is the code responsible for the billing process. It's mainly based on the Android documentation.

```
package ch.sooon.core.billing

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.Application
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent
import ch.sooon.core.Core
import ch.sooon.core.billing.BillingSecureCheck.verifyPurchase
import ch.sooon.core.dataflow.Bell
import ch.sooon.core.utils.CorePreferenceHelper
import com.android.billingclient.api.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class BillingManager private constructor (
    private val application: Application,
    private val defaultScope: CoroutineScope,
    skuList: List<String>
) : PurchasesUpdatedListener, BillingClientStateListener {

    companion object {
        private val TAG = BillingManager::class.java.simpleName

        @Volatile
        private var sInstance: BillingManager? = null
        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(
            application: Application,
            defaultScope: CoroutineScope,
            skuList: List<String>,
        ) = sInstance ?: synchronized(this) {
            sInstance ?: BillingManager(
                application,
                defaultScope,
                skuList,
            )
                .also { sInstance = it }
        }
    }

    private val mSkuList: List<String> = skuList
    private var skuDetails: SkuDetails? = null
    var skuDetailsStatusReceived = false

    private val purchaseConsumptionInProcess: MutableSet<Purchase> = HashSet()

    private val bell =  Bell(TAG)

    private val billingClient: BillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(application)
        .setListener(this)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()

    init {
        billingClient.startConnection(this)
    }


    /**
     * It's recommended to requery purchases during onResume.
     */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun resume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON_RESUME")
        // this just avoids an extra purchase refresh after we finish a billing flow
        if (billingClient.isReady) {
            if (!skuDetailsStatusReceived)
                defaultScope.launch {
                    querySkuDetails()
                }
            refreshPurchases()
        }
    }
    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(p0: BillingResult) {
        if (p0.responseCode ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            defaultScope.launch {
                querySkuDetails()
                refreshPurchases()
            }
        }
    }

    fun refreshPurchases() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing purchases.")
        val purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        val billingResult = purchasesResult.billingResult
        if (billingResult.responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem getting purchases: " + billingResult.debugMessage)
        } else {
            if (purchasesResult.purchasesList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                updatePremiumStatus(false)
                Log.d(TAG, "No purchase found to process")
            } else
                processPurchaseList(purchasesResult.purchasesList)
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing purchases finished.")
    }

    override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() { }
    /**
     * Goes through each purchase and makes sure that the purchase state is processed and the state
     * is available through Flows. Verifies signature and acknowledges purchases. PURCHASED isn't
     * returned until the purchase is acknowledged.
     *
     * https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes#2_0_acknowledge
     *
     * Developers can choose to acknowledge purchases from a server using the
     * Google Play Developer API. The server has direct access to the user database,
     * so using the Google Play Developer API for acknowledgement might be more reliable.
     *
     * If the purchase token is not acknowledged within 3 days,
     * then Google Play will automatically refund and revoke the purchase.
     * This behavior helps ensure that users are not charged unless the user has successfully
     * received access to the content.
     * This eliminates a category of issues where users complain to developers
     * that they paid for something that the app is not giving to them.
     *
     * If a skusToUpdate list is passed-into this method, any purchases not in the list of
     * purchases will have their state set to UNPURCHASED.
     *
     * @param purchases the List of purchases to process.
     * @param skusToUpdate a list of skus that we want to update the state from --- this allows us
     * to set the state of non-returned SKUs to UNPURCHASED.
     */
    private fun processPurchaseList(purchases: List<Purchase>?) {
        val updatedSkus = HashSet<String>()
        if (!purchases.isNullOrEmpty()){
            for (purchase in purchases) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Processing purchase $purchase")
                val sku = purchase.sku
                updatedSkus.add(sku)
                val purchaseState = purchase.purchaseState
                if (purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Purchase valid: $purchase")
                    if (!isSignatureValid(purchase)) {
                        Log.e(
                            TAG,
                            "Invalid signature on SKU $sku. Check to make sure your " +
                                    "public key is correct."
                        )
                        continue
                    }
                    // only set the purchased state after we've validated the signature.
                    if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                            // acknowledge everything --- new purchases are ones not yet acknowledged
                            val billingResult = billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(
                                AcknowledgePurchaseParams
                                    .newBuilder()
                                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                                    .build()
                            )
                            Log.d(TAG, "Acknowledgement attempted")
                            if (billingResult.responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Error acknowledging purchase: $sku: ${billingResult.responseCode} - ${billingResult.debugMessage}")
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Purchase acknowledged: $sku")
                                updatePremiumStatus(true)
                            }
                        }
                    } else{
                        updatePremiumStatus(true)
                    }
                } else {
                    updatePremiumStatus(false)
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Empty purchase list")
        }
    }

    private fun isSignatureValid(purchase: Purchase): Boolean {
        return verifyPurchase(purchase.originalJson, purchase.signature)
    }

    suspend fun querySkuDetails() {
        val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        params.setSkusList(mSkuList)
            .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)

        val skuDetailsResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            billingClient.querySkuDetails(params.build())
        }
        onSkuDetailsResponse(skuDetailsResult.billingResult, skuDetailsResult.skuDetailsList)
    }

    /**
     * Receives the result from [.querySkuDetailsAsync]}.
     *
     * Store the SkuDetails and post them in the [.skuDetailsMap]. This allows other
     * parts of the app to use the [SkuDetails] to show SKU information and make purchases.
     */
    private fun onSkuDetailsResponse(billingResult: BillingResult, skuDetailsList: List<SkuDetails>?) {
        val responseCode = billingResult.responseCode
        val debugMessage = billingResult.debugMessage
        when (responseCode) {
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse OK")
                if (skuDetailsList == null || skuDetailsList.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.e( TAG,
                        "onSkuDetailsResponse: " +
                                "Found null or empty SkuDetails. " +
                                "Check to see if the SKUs you requested are correctly published " +
                                "in the Google Play Console."
                    )
                } else {
                    skuDetailsStatusReceived = true
                    for (skuDetails in skuDetailsList) {
                        if (skuDetails.sku == Core.Setup.sku)
                            this.skuDetails = skuDetails
                    }
                }
            }
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED,
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.BILLING_UNAVAILABLE,
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_UNAVAILABLE,
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.DEVELOPER_ERROR,
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ERROR ->
                Log.e(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: $responseCode $debugMessage")
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED ->
                Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: $responseCode $debugMessage")
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED,
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED,
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_NOT_OWNED ->
                Log.wtf(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: $responseCode $debugMessage")
            else -> Log.wtf(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: $responseCode $debugMessage")
        }
    }

    override fun onPurchasesUpdated(billingResult: BillingResult, purchases: List<Purchase>?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated() called")
        when (billingResult.responseCode) {
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {
                if(!purchases.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    processPurchaseList(purchases)
                }
            }
            // BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED -> {}
            else -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "onPurchasedUpdated error ${billingResult.responseCode} : ${billingResult.debugMessage}")
            }
        }
        resume()
    }

    /**
     * Consumes an in-app purchase. Interested listeners can watch the purchaseConsumed LiveEvent.
     * To make things easy, you can send in a list of SKUs that are auto-consumed by the
     * BillingDataSource.
     */
    suspend fun consumeInAppPurchase(sku: String) {
        val pr = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        val br = pr.billingResult
        val purchasesList = pr.purchasesList
        if (br.responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem getting purchases: " + br.debugMessage)
        } else {
            if (!purchasesList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                for (purchase in purchasesList) {
                    if (purchase.sku == sku) {
                        consumePurchase(purchase)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to consume SKU: $sku Sku not found.")
    }


    /**
     * Internal call only. Assumes that all signature checks have been completed and the purchase
     * is ready to be consumed. If the sku is already being consumed, does nothing.
     * @param purchase purchase to consume
     */
    private suspend fun consumePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
        // weak check to make sure we're not already consuming the sku
        if (purchaseConsumptionInProcess.contains(purchase)) {
            // already consuming
            return
        }
        purchaseConsumptionInProcess.add(purchase)
        val consumePurchaseResult = billingClient.consumePurchase(
            ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                .build()
        )

        purchaseConsumptionInProcess.remove(purchase)
        if (consumePurchaseResult.billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Emitting sku.")
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while consuming: Code ${consumePurchaseResult.billingResult.responseCode} - ${consumePurchaseResult.billingResult.debugMessage}")
        }
        refreshPurchases()
    }


    fun launchPurchaseFlow(activity: Activity) {
        if (!skuDetailsStatusReceived) {
            defaultScope.launch {
                Core.billingManager.querySkuDetails()
            }
        }
        this.skuDetails?.let {
            val flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(it)
                .build()
            val launch = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams)
            Log.d(TAG, "launchPurchaseFlow result: ${launch.responseCode}: ${launch.debugMessage}")
        }
    }

    private fun updatePremiumStatus(newStatus: Boolean) {
        CorePreferenceHelper.savePremiumStatus(application, newStatus)
        bell.ring()
    }

    fun subscribe(function: () -> Unit) = bell.listen(function)
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you discover the solution?